# Count the amount of times a boolean goes from True to False in a column grouped by year in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a year column and a boolean column, and want to count how many times true changes to false by year.

| Year | Boolean |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | True |
| 2019 | False |
| 2019 | True |
| 2019 | False |
| 2020 | True |
| 2020 | True |
| 2020 | False |
| 2021 | False |
| 2021 | True |
| 2021 | True |
| 2021 | False |

My expected outcome would be an array or another df that looks like this

| Year | Changes |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | 2 |
| 2020 | 1 |
| 2021 | 1 |

I've used something like this to count the total number of True to False changes, but am unsure how to group them by year

```
(df.Col2 & (df.Col2 != df.Col2.shift(1))).sum()
```

Comment: Are you ever going to have something starting with False going to True?

Comment: Yes but I am only interested in True to False so starting with False doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count per group, for this you can group by year, convert the booleans to integers and count the -1 values after a `diff`:

```
df.groupby('Year')['Boolean'].apply(lambda s: s.astype(int).diff().eq(-1).sum())
```

variant with your initial approach:

```
df.groupby('Year')['Boolean'].apply(lambda s: (s&s.ne(s.shift())).sum())
```

output:

```
Year
2019    2
2020    1
2021    1
Name: Boolean, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['Changes'] = df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda b: ~b & b.shift(1).fillna(False))
```

df at this point:

```
    Year    Boolean Changes
0   2019    True    False
1   2019    False   True
2   2019    True    False
3   2019    False   True
4   2020    True    False
5   2020    True    False
6   2020    False   True
7   2021    False   False
8   2021    True    False
9   2021    True    False
10  2021    False   True
```

and then group and sum:

```
df = df.groupby('Year',as_index=False)['Changes'].sum()
```

Output:

```
    Year    Changes
0   2019    2
1   2020    1
2   2021    1
```